# Home Page that locks the apps and widgets in place

Tags: android, google-apps

With a stock home page app on the Samsung S6, I am sick of my apps and widgets moving around and getting deleted.  I am not alone, my wife has the same issue on thh Note 5.

Ideally a lock setting would do the trick.  But I don't think it exists.

Can someone recommened an app to replace the home page functions.  It must have a lock property or setting or an edit mode to lock the apps and widgets in place.  I dont care about wallppapers and themes.  And I am quite happy to pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher)** does support this. From its app description:

> Lock your desktop to prevent accidental changes

And even if you don't care about wallpapers, themes, etc – *Apex* supports all those. And much more, it is very flexible and adjustable. I've used it for years, and can highly recommend it.

To give you an alternative: Comparable in features as well as in look-and-feel is **[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)**. Taking the paid version of the two is almost a 100% match – they just slightly differ in what features are available with their free versions. I've never tried *Nova* myself, though.

So my recommendation: Give *Apex* a try. You'll most likely stay with it :)

Comment: I am trying it now.  Its a shame that the import feature did not work.  I will give it a decent try.

Comment: Just found the lock desktop setting, so I am ticking this answer.

Comment: Cool. Enjoy Apex (I really do ;)

Comment: Can be shameless and ask you to vote for my question please

Answer (score 1):

[Total Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.launcher2)

Its a very configurable launcher, locking is just one feature. You can even set a custom height and width (in pixels) for every single widget. Its a small 2MB download with many features, and the paid version isn't as expensive as the top brands.

Unlike other launchers, you can't technically add app shortcuts onto your home without a few tweaks. You can however add images onto your desktop, then set it to open an app, like how most other launchers work.